# phantomjs exception in thread

Tags: java, phantomjs

I have downloaded phantomjs 64-bit to a (brand new VPS) Centos 5.8. Java is installed and in the PATH. When I enter 'java phantomjs' in the containing directory for phantomjs I get

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: phantomjs 
Caused by: java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java.200) at ....."
```

and a series of ClassLoader errors.
I have scoured the net for clues as to what is causing this and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you come up with idea that phantomjs is Java app? `phantomjs` is Linux binary, just run it like `phantomjs` and that's it.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, that explains it ! I read in an article that it needed Java - but it must have been for something else.

Answer (score 1):

From the phantomjs [Quick Start](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start) page.

> This instruction assumes that PhantomJS is installed and its executable is placed somewhere in the PATH.

It is a native executable, not a Java application.  So naturally, the `java` command can't run it.  Do what the Quick Start document implies:

1. Add the directory containing the executable to your $PATH.
2. Type the "phantomjs" command using your Linux command shell.